# pass a array to format font color/weight ...

Tags: office-js

Is there a method such as numberFormat that takes a table to format the font colors, weights of the data in a table ?

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");

const formats = [
                ["red", "red"],
                ["red", "red"],
                ["red", "red"]
            ];

const range = sheet.getRange("D3:E5");
range.XXX = formats;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there isn't an API for that, but it is an interesting idea. Please suggest that at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

We are working on an API that would enable code to set different formatting values to different subranges with about the same amount of code as your suggestion, but it has not yet been determined whether it will be a property or method on the Range object itself.

Comment: Thanks @rick-kirkham.  I have posted a [new idea](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34132915-use-an-array-to-format-font-color-weight) at Office Developer Voice.